# View with height = 0.5 not always visible on iPad 2

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a few text fields and separator views between them that have a height of 0.5 pixels that is set via Auto Layout.

*Problem:*

Sometimes some of the separators are invisible, other times they become visible but some others become invisible instead.

Is it because iPad 2 doesn't have a Retina display and things that are less than 1 pixel get rounded to 0 or 1 pixel?

If so, what is the easiest way to make them always end up 1 pixel in size on such devices? I was thinking of making a custom UIView subclass for separators that would have a height of 0.5 on Retina displays and 1 pixel otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a view to a height of `0.5` has issues on various screens. On the iPad 2 it may result in the view not being visible at all, because it doesn't have a retina screen and thus there are no corresponding pixels for a 0.5pt line. On an iPhone Plus with its 3x screen you will most likely also get alias effects.

To properly set a thin line on various screens (from what I can say, that's what Apple does e.g. with their table view separators), you need to calculate the width based on the screen.

Given your receiver is a `UIView` that owns the line view you want to configure, this should do the trick:

Objective-C:
`CGFloat lineHeight = 1.0/self.contentScaleFactor;`

Swift:
`let lineHeight = 1.0/contentScaleFactor`

You could do that e.g. in `didMoveToWindow` in the view, as the scale could theoretically change when moving windows. This is rare on iOS but potentially your view could be shown on an external screen.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a Retina issue!

what you can make is a extension to the UIView class where it checks if a view have a width/height less than 1 and the screen is non retina then it round it up to 1 or 0 accordingly.

Hope this helps!